# How much should I worry about these messages?

Tags: security

I received about 50 messages today with the similar message:

> WordPress Firewall has detected and blocked a potential attack!
>
> Web Page: 
>     domain.com/index.php?option=com_simpledownload&controller=../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../proc/self/environ%00
>   Warning: URL may contain dangerous content! Offending IP: 
>     211.147.221.42 [ Get IP location ] Offending Parameter:     controller = ../../../../../../../../../../../../../../../proc/self/environ
>
> This may be a "Directory Traversal Attack."

How much should I worry about these? It came from multiple IP addresses throughout the day.

Comment: Harmless. These type of requests are quite normal. And that "wordpress firewall" thing is probably useless...

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but I had to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is very common, it is a malicious query string most likely (99% time) done by a bot, I think `option=com_simpledownload` is actually a Joomla plugin, so obviously it won't effect WordPress.

You can see the detials here, http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2010-2122